# loop over files to pass as arguments to a script

Tags: shell-script

I have a script `some.sh` that loops over several files;

```
#!/bin/bash
path_to_destin ="/some/path/"
path_to_raw ="some/other/path"
list = "001 002 003"
for l in $list
do
    mkdir $path_to_destin/output_$l
    python somescript.py -input $path_to_raw/dir_$l -output $path_to_destin/output_$l/table_$l.txt 
done
```

This script generates three files `table_001.q`, `table_002.q` and `table_003.q`.

After the loop, another script take as input these files,

```
some_other_script -i table_001.q -i table_002.q -i table_003.q -o all.q
```

Is there a way to run as many `-i table_***` as it is indicated in `$list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

indir='/some/other/path'
outdir='/some/path'

list=( 001 002 003 )

for i in "${list[@]}"; do
    mkdir -p "$outdir/output_$i"
    python somescript.py -input "$indir/dir_$i" -output "$outdir/output_$i/table_$i.txt"

    inargs+=( -i "table_$i.q" )
done

some_other_script "${inargs[@]}" -o all.q
```

Observations:

1. Assignments may not have space around `=`.
2. Indentation and whitespace improves readability.
3. Don't loop over strings, loop over arrays.
4. Quote all variable expansions.

Regarding quoting of variable expansions:

- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)
- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: Thank you for your input and the solution, really helpful!